Remove velocity dependent terms in a Lagrangian by redefinition
I'm trying to simplify a Lagrangian so it only depends on kinetic energy, masses and interactions and I want to remove velocity dependent terms. I call $\vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix} x & y & z \end{pmatrix}$, then I am interested in
\begin{equation}
   \mathcal{L} = \dot{\vec{v}}^TM_{\text{Kin}}(t)\dot{\vec{v}} + \dot{\vec{v}}^TM_{\text{vel}}(t)\vec{v} + \vec{v}^TM_{\text{mass&int}}(t)\vec{v}
\end{equation}
I considered the simplest possible system with 3 variables and these velocity terms
\begin{equation}
   \mathcal{L} = \dot x^2 + \dot y^2 + \dot z^2 + A\dot x y + B\dot x z + F(x,y,z)
 \end{equation}
Where $A$,$B$ are constants. I want to remove velocity dependent terms with a redefinition
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        x \\ y \\ z
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{13} \\ c_{21} & c_{22} & c_{23} \\ c_{31} & c_{32} & c_{33}
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        X \\ Y \\ Z
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
So that my matrix of velocities becomes diagonal. Then, the diagonal terms are equivalent to mass terms modulo boundary terms
\begin{equation}
   Q\dot{X}X = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{Q}{2}X^2 \right) - \frac{\dot{Q}}{2}X^2
\end{equation}
If the change of the basis matrix $C$ has constant coefficients, then in general there are cases (like mine) where the velocity matrix is not diagonalizable. If it depends on time, I have found a basis change with two variables $x(t)$, $y(t)$ that works. For 3 variables, however, I struggle. I end up with this
\begin{equation}
     2C(t)^T \dot{C}(t) + C^T(t)M_{\text{vel}}C(t) = \hat{M}_{vel}
\end{equation}
And I tried to find out if $\hat{M}_{vel}$ could be diagonal for some $C(t)$. Doing it algebraically or trying to solve it element by element didn't work for me. I think I've tried this in various ways, and I think that in general you can't eliminate these terms, but I haven't found a satisfactory proof or example. I have also failed to find it in the literature. Any ideas?

Comment: the matrix $\hat{M}_{\text{vel}}$ dont need to be diagonal, if it is symmetric then is equivalent to a boundary term also.

Some friend found and answer and I am posting it here. I completed this solution with more considerations, to also make sure the kinetic term is simultaneously diagonalized.
The $M_{kin}$ matrix is symmetric by construction as e.g. $3\dot{x}\dot{y} + 7\dot{y}\dot{x} = 5\dot{x}\dot{y} + 5\dot{y}\dot{x}$, can be taken as symmetric. Then is diagonalizable, and also invertible (else, the mode with null eigenvalue is a Lagrange multiplier, you eliminate then and continue with the resulting system).
You can diagonalize $M_{kin}$ with some unitary $Q(t)$, which change $M_{v}$ and $M_{mass}$, however as they are arbitrary you dont care. Then, if $M_{kin}$ is definite positive you can redefine variables, $\bar{x} \rightarrow \lambda_x(t) x$, using integration by parts you end with $M_{kin}=I$ is the identity matrix.
Then, you take another change of variables $x = C(t)X$, and you end with equation
\begin{equation}
2C^T \dot{C} + C^T M_v C = \hat{M}_v
\end{equation}
You want $\hat{M}_v$ to be symmetric, but is simpler to take it 0. Then
\begin{equation}
 2C^T \dot{C} + C^T M_v C = 0 \implies C^T \left( \dot{C} + \frac{M_v}{2} C \right) = 0
\end{equation}
A possible solution is
\begin{equation}
\dot{C} = - \frac{M_v}{2} C
\end{equation}
As you can add any symmetric matrix to $M_{vel}$, as this represents a total derivative into the action (e.g. $2\dot{x}y + 2 x\dot{y}$) then you turn it antisymmetric, and then is normal and diagonalizable. The solution is (taking $3 \times 3$ C matrix as a 9D vector)
\begin{equation}
\dot{C} = \begin{pmatrix}
        M_{11} \mathcal{I} & M_{12} \mathcal{I} & M_{13} \mathcal{I} \\ M_{21} \mathcal{I} & M_{22} \mathcal{I}  & M_{23} \mathcal{I} \\ M_{31} \mathcal{I}  & M_{32} \mathcal{I}  & M_{33} \mathcal{I} \end{pmatrix} C
\end{equation}
Where $MI$ is 9x9 vectorization of $M$, and has same diagonalization by blocks as $3x3$ M, therefore is diagonalizable. Then $C = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\int dt M(t)}$ is the solution of the problem.
As $C(t)$ is the exponential of a antisymmetric matrix, then is unitary $C^T = C^{-1}$ and then the kinetic term $\hat{M}_{kin} = C^T C = \mathcal{I}$ remains diagonal. Then you have simultaneously eliminated the velocity terms and diagonalized the kinetic matrix. The price to pay is that the masses, couplings and the relation with the original variables will be complicated.
